# How to pass parameters in 'Run' method of the scheduling agent in Sitecore

Tags: scheduled-tasks, scheduler-job

I want to pass class object parameter to the `Run` method of the scheduling agent in the Sitecore.

Can I pass object parameter to the method and how?

How can I configure param in the config file?

Class:

```
public class ImportProduct
{
    public void Run()
    {
        //Scheduling Agent calling
    }
}
```

Config:

```
<scheduling>
    <agent type="******.SchedulingAgent.ImportProduct" method="Run" interval="00:02:00">
    </agent>
</scheduling>
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pass a parameter to `Run()` method but you can

- set a property on your job class,
- or pass constructor parameter, assign to a field and use it in your code.

See the `UrlAgent` class configuration:

```
<agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.UrlAgent" method="Run" interval="00:15:00">
  <param desc="url">/sitecore/service/keepalive.aspx</param>
  <LogActivity>true</LogActivity>
</agent>
```

and how it's used in the class:

```
public class UrlAgent
{
  private readonly string _url;
  private bool _logActivity = true;

  public UrlAgent(string url)
  {
    this._url = url;
  }

  public bool LogActivity
  {
    get => this._logActivity;
    set => this._logActivity = value;
  }

  public void Run()
  {
      string fullUrl = WebUtil.GetFullUrl(this._url);
      if (this.LogActivity)
      {
          ...
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters in a constructor as Sitecore already uses in `PublishAgent`.

Config:

```
<agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.PublishAgent" method="Run" interval="00:00:00" role:require="Standalone or Reporting or ContentManagement">
      <param desc="source database">master</param>
      <param desc="target database">web</param>
      <param desc="mode (full or smart or incremental)">incremental</param>
      <param desc="languages">en, da</param>
    </agent>
```

Class

```
public class PublishAgent
{
    private readonly List<Language> _languages;

    private readonly PublishMode _mode;

    private readonly string _sourceDatabase;

    private readonly string _targetDatabase;

    public List<Language> Languages => _languages;

    public PublishMode Mode => _mode;

    public string SourceDatabase => _sourceDatabase;

    public string TargetDatabase => _targetDatabase;

    public PublishAgent(string sourceDatabase, string targetDatabase, string mode, string languages)
    {
        _sourceDatabase = sourceDatabase;
        _targetDatabase = targetDatabase;
        _languages = ParseLanguages(languages);
        _mode = ParseMode(mode);
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        //You can read those parameters here and do your custom code.
        Database database = Factory.GetDatabase(_sourceDatabase);
        Database database2 = Factory.GetDatabase(_targetDatabase);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!